# 「ヒラギノ明朝-Pro-W6.ttf」フォントのエラー

Tags: font

こんにちは！

「ヒラギノ明朝-Pro-W6.ttf」フォントを開くと、下記のエラーが出る

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

教えていただけませんか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ヒラギノのフォントは有償フォントであり購入されたものだと思いますが、それならば購入店に相談するのが筋でしょう。

Comment: ヒラギノのフォントは購入済です。
有償フォントとは、一つパソコンしか利用できないと認識と合っているでしょうか。

Comment: サポートに関して検索してみましたが、以下のように1ライセンス1PCのようですね[1.3 購入したフォントを複数台のコンピュータで使用したいが可能ですか？](http://www.screen.co.jp/ga_product/sento/support/licensefaq.html#anchor1-3)

Comment: FWIW: 商用製品の、プログラミングに関する Q&A がスタックオーバーフロー上にあることそれ自体は、禁止されているわけではありません。  https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: 放置していると「○○というツールを使ってホゲホゲ」などと違法なことを勧める人もでるかと思って質問を見てすぐに敢えてツッケンドンな回答をしました。

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。